# Is Lightning Active on iPad - Summer 16

Tags: summer-16

I just want to know if Lightning is active by default on ipads from Summer 16 ? Please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

I presume by 'Lightning' you mean 'Lightning Experience' here. Also, assuming that on iPad - it refers to the 'Salesforce1 app'.

The latest version of the Salesforce1 iPad app was released [on June 13](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/salesforce1/id404249815?mt=8) and it does support Lightning Experience by default.

Answer (score 1):

Lightning Experience isn't available for mobile browsers, unfortunately:

[Supported Browsers for Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=getstart_browsers_sfx.htm&language=en_US)

If you attempt to log into Salesforce with an ipad browser (or android browser), Salesforce will direct the user the Salesforce 1 browser experience.

If you have Lightning Experience switched on, but switch off the Salesforce1 browser re-direct in the settings (Mobile Settings in setup), the browser seems to just hang (but I've only tested on Android Chrome).